# Which identity properties are required to be SCIM compliant?

Tags: scim, scim2

Maybe I didn't really get the concept but basicly if you say you're compatible with SCIM then there must be certain expectations of properties that belong to identities am I right?

For an example if you take a look at the example createUser request from

https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/implement-scim-api

you will see a variety of different properties like `displayName`, `nickName` etc..

My use case however requires only one name, the `userName`.

My question is, are any of these even required to say that you are SCIM compliant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RFC7643](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643) indicates that the `id` parameter must be included.

The requirement for the other properties depends on the resource type and thus schemas used by your application. For a user resource, the [section 4.1 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-4.1) indicates that the `userName` is also required.

Comment: I see, so SCIM pretty much doesnt exactly mean you have all the additional information available but rather if you want to add them then add them with these names..